# "Well [noun] is here to rescue" 

Tags: grammaticality

> Well [some noun here] is here to rescue.

Does the structure of sentence sound good? Please suggest some example sentences where "to rescue" can be used.

Comment: Is the 'something' coming to rescue or in need of rescue? In the first case, you would say 'the rescue'.

Comment: I am sorry, but proofreading is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, its doesn't read well. Typically you might say:

*"Someone came to the rescue, and saved the kitten"*

or perhaps:

*"it would be an act of kindness to rescue a kitten from danger"*

Answer (score 0):

**"*Well, at last, here's something to our (/their/the ...) rescue*"**

...should be OK, if you really mean the 'something' coming in as a god-send in the nick of time, so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

[**Rescue**](http://www.wordnik.com/words/rescue) can be a verb or a noun.
As a verb, "rescue" is *transitive* - it requires an object.

You can

- rescue your homework from the trash
- rescue a kitten from a tree

but you can't just "rescue".

As a noun, "rescue" requires an article (**a** or **the**) or a possessive pronoun (**your**, **my**, **his**, etc.)

So you can say

- Who will come to **my** rescue?
- "Look - it's the IT consultant, here to **the** rescue!"
- Johnny performed **a** rescue today at the swimming pool.

Comment: Could the O.P.'s sentence structure be used when the object is obvious or implied? As in, "Who will rescue that drowning man?" "Look! The lifeguard is here to rescue!" (I'm not trying to be a smart aleck, it's a genuine question.  While I acknowledge such usage would be rare, it still seems passable in certain contexts.)

Comment: @J.R. - Although, in the heat of the moment (the man IS drowning, after all) I doubt that anyone would correct your grammar... still: no, that would not be correct.  There are verbs that can be used both transitively and intransitively, but "rescue" is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You should omit "well". Alternatively, you could add a comma after "well".

In any case, you need an object (who/what is being rescued).

**Example Sentences and Variations**

- Jane has gotten herself into trouble once again. **Well, Peter is here to rescue **her**, as usual.
- Spotty dashed across the street to rescue his bone, but it was too late.
- When Mark lost his daughter in an accident, his friends came to his rescue.